# uncaught type error object has no method 'to top scroller'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i got the plugin from this link http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-For-Smooth-Scroll-To-Top-Bottom-scrollToTop.html.i attcahed the code below of my index.html.i tried many jquery plugin but it did n't work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,    maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Pharmaceutical</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/favi.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,800,700,600,500,300,200,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>  
<body>
<!-- wrapper -->
 <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- shell -->
    <div class="shell">

    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- header -->
        <header id="header">
            <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Retina</a></h1>
            <!-- search -->
            <div class="search">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="field" value="keywords here ..." title="keywords here ..." />
                    <input type="submit" class="search-btn" value="" />
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- end of search -->
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        </header>
        <!-- end of header -->
        <!-- navigaation -->
        <div id="menu">
         <ul class="menu">
         <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a>
        <div><ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>About us</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>History</span></a>
                <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Medicine</span></a>
                        <div><ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Generic</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Branded</span></a></li>
                        </ul></div>
                    </li>
                </ul></div>
               </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Doctors</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>pharmaceutical establishment</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Contact us</span></a></li>
        </ul></div>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Doctors zone</span></a>
        <div><ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Search Doctors</span></a>
                <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="main.php"><span>By area</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>By disease</span></a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Doctors visits</span></a>
                <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>By area</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>By state</span></a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Doctors Reaserch</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Doctors specialization</span></a></li>
        </ul></div>
         </li>
       <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Pharmaceutical zone</span></a>
        <div><ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Search Pharmacies</span></a>
                <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>By area</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Door delivery</span></a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Offer zone</span></a>
                <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Medicine offer</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Cosmetics offer</span></a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
        </ul></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Ask questions</span></a>
        <div><ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>To doctors</span></a>
                <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>By area</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>By disease</span></a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>To pharmacies</span>  </a>
                <div><ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>By area</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Get a contact details</span></a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
        </ul></div>
      </li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Online Appointment Fixing</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Donate</span></a></li>
    &nbsp;<li class="last"><img src="css/images/ini.png" alt="" /></li>
              </ul>
                   </div>
        <!-- end of navigation -->
        <!-- slider-holder -->
        <div class="slider-holder">

            <!-- slider -->
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="socials">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="facebook-ico">facebook-ico</a>
                    <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="twitter-ico">twitter-ico</a>
                    <a href="https://secure.skype.com/portal/overview" class="skype-ico">skype-ico</a>
                    <a href="#" class="rss-ico">rss-ico</a>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>

                <div class="arrs">
                    <a href="#" class="prev-arr"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="next-arr"></a>
                </div>

                <ul>
                    <li id="img1">
                        <div class="slide-cnt">
                            <h4>MEDICAL CHECKUP</h4>
                            <h2>Free medical test..let's     go</h2>
                            <p>Free CMR scan,full body scan,pressure,sugar checkup is in progress! <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="css/images/cli7.png" alt="" />
                    </li>

                    <li id="img2">
                        <div class="slide-cnt">
                            <h4>CLINICAL SHOPPING</h4>
                            <h2>Get near by clinical and testing shop!</h2>
                            <p>Find a near by clinical shop and blood testing centres! <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="css/images/cli5.png" alt="" />
                    </li>

                    <li id="img3">
                        <div class="slide-cnt">
                            <h4>DOCTORS AND MEDICAL S       sHOOPING</h4>
                            <h2>Let check out the medicine</h2>
                            <p>find a nearby medical shop and Doctors..let's acquire a offer!<a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="css/images/cli1.png" alt="" />
                    </li>

                    <li id="img4">
                        <div class="slide-cnt">
                            <h4>EXPLORE YOUR IDEAS AND CHECK MEDICAL STRATEGY</h4>
                            <h2>upload your nearby details</h2>
                            <p>let help others to know about all the stuff about pharmaceutical details!<a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="css/images/mac-img.png" alt="" />
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- end of slider -->

            <!-- thumbs -->
            <div id="thumbs-wrapper">
                <div id="thumbs">
                    <a href="#img1" class="selected"><img src="css/images/cli7.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#img2"><img src="css/images/cli5.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#img3"><img src="css/images/cli1.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#img4"><img src="css/images/mac-img.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <a id="prev" href="#"></a>
                <a id="next" href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- end of thumbs -->
        </div>

        <!-- main -->
        <div class="main">

            <div class="featured">
                <h4>Welcome to <strong>Pharmaceutical Datawarehouse.</strong> Login to know all the stuff about Doctors and Medicines <strong>FREE!</strong>Explore and acquire the Life things</h4>
                <a href="login.php" class="blue-btn">GET IN TOUCH</a>
            </div>

            <section class="cols">
                <div class="col">
                    <h3>Daily Health Tips</h3>
                    <img src="css/images/fruit.png" alt="" class="left"/>
                    <h5>Make your day healthy and hygienic</h5>
                    <p>All foods made from meat, poultry, seafood, beans and peas, eggs, processed soy products, nuts, and seeds are considered part of the Protein Foods Group. Beans and peas are also part of the Vegetable Group. For more information on beans and peas, see Beans and Peas Are Unique Foods. <br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <h3>We’re Hiring</h3>
                    <img src="css/images/hiring.png" alt="" class="left"/>
                    <h5>We are looking people for doing health services </h5>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                    <p>Make our country disease free!let's join your hand with us to serve for the humanity!Just login to register your valuable service <br /><a href="#" class="more">Click here to LOGIN</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <h3>Our Services</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Get a Doctor details near by your area</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grab the Hospitals details near by your area </a></li></br></br>
                        <video width="250" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="hygiene.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                         <source src="hygiene.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                         <source src="hygiene.webm" type="video/webm">
                        <object data="hygiene.mp4" width="250" height="240">
                        <embed src="hygiene.mp4" width="250" height="240">
                          </object> 
                          </video>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </section>

            <section class="entries">
                <div class="entry">
                    <h3>Latest Blog Posts</h3>
                    <div class="entry-inner">
                        <div class="date">
                            <strong>01</strong>
                            <span>2012</span>
                            <em>feb</em>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cnt">
                            <p><a href="#">pharmaceutical<br /> Reaserch</a></p>
                            <p class="meta"><a href="#">by John Doe </a> /  <a href="#">Cipla pharma</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry-inner">
                        <div class="date">
                            <strong>28</strong>
                            <span>2012</span>
                            <em>jan</em>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cnt">
                            <p><a href="#">Research in thyroid<br /> bones</a></p>
                            <p class="meta"><a href="#">by shaullah</a> /  <a href="#">Sun pharma</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry-inner">
                        <div class="date">
                            <strong>11</strong>
                            <span>2012</span>
                            <em>feb</em>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cnt">
                            <p><a href="#">Medical awareness<br /> Camp</a></p>
                            <p class="meta"><a href="#">by indian government </a> /  <a href="#">Awareness camp</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="entry">
                    <h3>Latest Project</h3>
                    <h5>Recent summer projects completed by MSc Medical Microbiology students </h5>
                    <a href="#"><img src="css/images/pro.png" a   alt="" /></a>
                    <p> Analysis of Human Antibody Responses to   a Novel Polymorphic Plasmodium falciparum Merozoite Protein from the Antigenic Rich Region of Chromosome <br /><a href="#" class="more">view more</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="entry">
                    <h3>Testimonials</h3>

                    <div class="testimonials">                  
                        <p><strong>“</strong>Pharmaceutical    Datawarehouse really doing well and the serving for the humanity to be healthy and hygienic”</p>
                        <p class="author">John Doe,    <strong>Cipla Pharma</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="partners">
                        <h3>Our Partners</h3>
                        <img src="css/images/partners-img.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- end of main -->
        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

        <!-- footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="footer-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Doctors zone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pharamaceutical Zone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ask aQuestion </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get a free health tips</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Donate us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <p class="copy">&copy; Copyright 2012<span>|</span>Sitename. Design by <a href="http://chocotemplates.com" target="_blank">Nawaz</a></p>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of footer -->

       </div>
       <!-- end of container -->
  </div>
   <!-- end of shell -->
    </div>
       <!-- end of wrapper -->
       <div id="totopscroller"> </div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#totopscroller').totopscroller({link:'http://www.jqueryscript.net'});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first step in finding any errors on your web page is to open the debugger (press the F12 key) then click on the Console tab. What errors are reported there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is about that plugin is not inited. You init plugin before `jQuery`:

```
<script src="js/jquery.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Change to this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="js/jquery.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```